# Maven Update Project Configuration issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Whenever I perform a Maven Update Project Configuration, I loose ay of the projects I have listed in eclipse under the Java Build Path/Projects. Is there a plugin or something that I need to add to the pom.xml to make it reconfigure that whenever I update the project configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Maven-based dependency management, you are not supposed to have any projects under Java Build Path/Projects. Instead, those projects should be Maven projects with Maven nature enabled. Then all you need to do is to have them declared as dependencies of your project and enable option to resolve Maven dependencies from Eclipse workspace (it is enabled by default).

Comment: Interesting.. thank you for that tip. I was doing everything as you mentioned except my dependency projects had type "war' instead of "jar" in the dependency list. This fixed the issue I was having. Now, because I set them as jars, I can't overlay my projects which was my original intent. How do I go about doing that?